# Mockserver expectation not active

Tags: spring-boot, junit, apache-camel, mockserver

Context is a Junit test, setup with Spring-boot, Mockserver and Camel.

Problem is that mocked response of the **verified** request is not matched during the test.

The logs :

```
INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : 8087 received request:

  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "/api/installation/organizations",
    "headers" : {
      "content-length" : [ "0" ],
      "User-Agent" : [ "Java/11.0.13" ],
      "Host" : [ "localhost:8087" ],
      "Connection" : [ "keep-alive" ],
      "Accept" : [ "application/json" ]
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : false
  }

INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : 8087 no expectation for:

  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "/api/installation/organizations",
    "headers" : {
      "content-length" : [ "0" ],
      "User-Agent" : [ "Java/11.0.13" ],
      "Host" : [ "localhost:8087" ],
      "Connection" : [ "keep-alive" ],
      "Accept" : [ "application/json" ]
    },
    "keepAlive" : true,
    "secure" : false
  }

 returning response:

  {
    "statusCode" : 404,
    "reasonPhrase" : "Not Found"
  }

INFO 1841843 --- [           main] b.h.c.route.CsvRouteBuilderTest          : Started CsvRouteBuilderTest in 6.17 seconds (JVM running for 8.32)
INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : retrieved requests and responses in json that match:

  { }

DEBUG 1841843 --- [           main] b.h.c.route.CsvRouteBuilderTest          : RecordedRequestsAndResponses: 12
INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : 8087 retrieved 0 active expectations in json that match:

  { }

DEBUG 1841843 --- [           main] b.h.c.route.CsvRouteBuilderTest          : activeExpectations: 0
INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : retrieved recorded expectations in json that match:

  { }

DEBUG 1841843 --- [           main] b.h.c.route.CsvRouteBuilderTest          : recordedExpectations: 0
INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : 8087 verifying requests that match:

  {
    "httpRequest" : {
      "method" : "GET",
      "path" : "/api/installation/organizations"
    },
    "times" : {
      "atLeast" : 1
    }
  }

INFO 1841843 --- [erver-EventLog4] org.mockserver.log.MockServerEventLog    : request:

  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "path" : "/api/installation/organizations"
  }

 found at least once
```

And the code :

```
@ExtendWith(MockServerExtension.class)
@MockServerSettings(ports = {8087})
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@DisableJmx
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class CsvRouteBuilderTest {

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    private MockServerClient mockServerClient;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEachLifecyleMethod(MockServerClient client) {
        mockServerClient = client;
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setupMocks() {
        mockServerClient
            .when(
                request().withMethod("GET").withPath(HDConnectProxyRestTemplate.URI_GET_INSTALLATION_ORGANIZATIONS)
                    .withHeader(Header.header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())))
            .respond(
                response("{data}").withContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
```

What did I miss ? I can see that both Camel and Mockserver are running at the moment of the test. But the mocked response should be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that spring-boot's context is starting the Camel logic before the unit test itself.

So, at the test, the Camel route was already running, and the mock-server expectations were not available.

In order to properly test this situation, I needed to :

1. First prevent the Camel route to start (for example with the Route.configure() method),
2. Initialize the mocks and their expectations (@Before each test),
3. Then, specifically enable the Camel route, during the Junit test.

Answer (score 0):

As the `MockServerExtension` starts the mock server thanks to the `BeforeAllCallback`, another way could be to initialize the mocker server `beforeAll` as next:

```
@BeforeAll
static void setupMocks(MockServerClient mockServerClient) {
    mockServerClient
        .when(
            request().withMethod("GET").withPath(HDConnectProxyRestTemplate.URI_GET_INSTALLATION_ORGANIZATIONS)
                .withHeader(Header.header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString())))
        .respond(
            response("{data}").withContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
}
```

This way your mock server will be configured before the start up of Camel.

Comment: I had tested with the @BeforeAll annotation already but Spring-boot loads the Camel context and the Route before it initializes the unit test. The only solution is to disable the Camel route I needed to test.

Comment: I tested your use case, I could reproduce and I could fix it with what I propose in this answer. The camel context is actually started on `postProcessTestInstance` which happens after `beforeAll` callbacks unless you annotate your test class with `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)`. If it is not the case, your problem is elsewhere: maybe it is due to the version of Spring Boot and/or Camel that you use or your environment, please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I will re-test thx

Comment: @Dino Have you retested it?

Comment: No yet, I had found another solution before that, based on spring-test MockRestServiceServer class. I will put an update when possible